# FB API - Is it possible to post a large photo on someone's wall?

Tags: facebook

I'm wondering if is it possible to post a large photo on someone's wall? Right now there is a limit - 90px, but how about the new Open Graph? Is it possible to do with the OG and the timeline?

Comment: Yes i also want this functionality in my facebook application wall posting please share with us if you know thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To get the nice big photos, you'll need to mark them as user-generated.

See here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/usergeneratedphotos/